# Prevent Duplicates From Being Saved In Database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have produced an console application which saves data using Entity Framework , I have a table which is designed like this:

```
ID     People_ID   People_Address    People_Postcode
---    ----------  --------------    ----------------
1       2          76 Nation Road     B27 8NT
2       7          88 Grimestone Road B45 9WG
3       12         45 Wallock Road    B22 4UI
```

To ensure duplicates are not be stored within the table the following code has been written:

```
ppl.People_Address = Address;
ppl.People_Postcode = Postcode;
ppl.People_ID = usr.ID;


If(db.tbl_people.Any(x=> x.people_address != ppl.People_Address) && (db.tbl_people.Any(x=> x.people_postcode != ppl.People_Postcode) &&  (db.tbl_people.Any(x=> x.People_ID != ppl.People_ID) {

db.tbl_people.Add(ppl)
db.SaveChanges();
}
```

However nothing is being added regardless if nothing exists in the table to compare to , any help??

Comment: this should be VERY easy to debug yourself. Just check all the statements in the if statement. Likely a type doesn't match or the case in a string is different. Either way your the person best placed to fix this and there is likely little anyone here can do to help

Comment: Just make those columns in your SQL database unique

Answer (score 1):

You will need to check for each of your fields if they are `null`. For example:

```
x.people_address != ppl.People_Address || x.people_adress == null
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few problems with this code.

First, you should not cause the database many times per calling "db.tbl_people" property getter. Do it one time and don't retrieve whole db collection.

Second, for the empty database

```
db.tbl_people.Any(x=> x.people_address != ppl.People_Address)
```

returns false because there is no entities in the tbl_people collection.

And the third your condition is not really check duplicates in the database.

Your query can be looks like code below:

```
// if there is no entities with same properties
if(db.tbl_people.Count(p => p.people_address == ppl.People_Address 
                         && p.people_postcode == ppl.People_postcode 
                         && p.People_ID == ppl.People_ID) == 0)
{
    // then save new entity
    db.tbl_people.Add(ppl)
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

This code will generate query to the database which will return just scalar variable and it'll be better to performance and communication channel.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the condition

```
if (db.tbl_people.Any(x=> x.people_address != ppl.People_Address)
    && (db.tbl_people.Any(x=> x.people_postcode != ppl.People_Postcode)
    && (db.tbl_people.Any(x=> x.People_ID != ppl.People_ID)
```

it should really be

```
if (!db.tbl_People.Any(x => x.people_address == ppl.People_Address
    && x.people_postcode == ppl.People_Postcode
    && x.People_ID == ppl.People_ID))
{
    // No duplicate
}
```